# Using spl_autoload() not able to load class

Tags: php, spl, spl-autoloader

I'm playing around with the SPL autoload functionality and seem to be missing something important as I am currently unable to get it to work. Here is the snippet I am currently using:

```
// ROOT_DIRECTORY translates to /home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test
define('ROOT_DIRECTORY', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('INCLUDE_DIRECTORY', ROOT_DIRECTORY . '/includes/classes/');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . INCLUDE_DIRECTORY);
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php, .interface.php, .abstract.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

When I `echo get_include_path()` I do get the path I expected:

```
// Output echo get_include_path();
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test/includes/classes/
```

However when I run the code I get this error message:

> Fatal error: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Class Request could not be loaded in
>   /home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test/contact.php
>   on line 5

Request.class.php is *definitely* in the /home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test/includes/classes/ directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Yannis Rizos - That is indeed my problem. Make this an answer so I can vote it up and give you credit for the correct answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a comment (anonymous) on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#96804 that may apply to your problem: spl_autoload_register() doesn't seem to play nice with camelcase, and in your case could be trying to find request.class.php instead of Request...

Comment: I have found this bug as well. As soon as I changed the class name to lower case all worked fine. Do you know if this has been reported as a bug?

Comment: There are bugs open for this.  Ridiculous that it's still an issue.  I went through the bug system and voted on relevant ones, here's a good place to start: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53065.

Comment: If you still want to use spl, you can use a closure that overloads the default function so you don't get lowercased: `spl_autoload_register( function( $class )
{
 include $class . '.php';
});
` - tune your paths ;)

Comment: Not necessarily a huge deal, but NOT using the default spl_autoload() and defining your own generates a performance hit due to the stat() execution generated during the include function... saw it in comments on php docs...

Answer (score 0):

The path where the class is supposed to be seems not to match the path were you expect them. Compare

```
.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test/includes/classes/
```

with

```
/home/someuser/public_html/subdomains/test/
```

The difference is, that your class is not in `includes/classes/` as your SPL requires it but a few directories above.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message but my issue was different. My error message looked like

```
PHP Fatal error:  spl_autoload(): Class Lib\Lib\Regex could not be loaded in /dir1/dir2/lib/regex.php on line 49
```

It turned out I forgot to remove the `Lib\` from `Lib\Regex` inside the Regex class definition itself. I had something like the following:

```
namespace Lib;

class Regex {

...

   public static function match($pattern, $str) {

      $regex = new Lib\Regex($pattern);

      ...
   }
}
```